# How do I make a button with multiple nested borders?

Tags: wpf

I want to make a button that has borders like this

[image: A button with a border offset from the button (or a background colored inner border)]

So far, I had an idea of putting the button in a grid and then making multiple borders around the grid, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just nest as many Border elements as necessary:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="6">
    <Border Background="SteelBlue" BorderBrush="White"
            BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4.5" Padding="40,6">
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="Text"/>
    </Border>
</Border>
```